# How to rescue custom exceptions coming from a middleware in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, middleware

I have a Rails 3.2 application that uses [Apartment](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment/), which is used as a middleware. Apartment throws an `Apartment::SchemaNotFound` exception and there is no way to rescue it with `rescue_from` from the `ApplicationController`. I thought I'd use `config.exceptions_app` as described in point #3 in [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/), but I can't set the router as the exception app, I assume I have to create my own.

So the question is: **How do I proceed?**

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with another piece of middleware throwing a custom exception, so I haven't actually looked at Apartment at all, but maybe something like this:

```
#app/middleware/apartment/rescued_apartment_middleware.rb
module Apartment
  class RescuedApartmentMiddleware < Apartment::Middleware
    def call(env)
      begin
        super
      rescue Apartment::SchemaNotFound
        env[:apartment_schema_not_found] = true # to be later referenced in your ApplicationController
        @app.call(env) # the middleware call method should return this, but it was probably short-circuited by the raise
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your environment:

```
config.middleware.use(Apartment::RescuedApartmentMiddleware, etc)
```

To access the env variable you set from ApplicationController or any controller:

```
if request.env[:apartment_schema_not_found]
  #handle
end
```

Combo of [How to rescue from a OAuth::Unauthorized exception in a Ruby on Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227440/how-to-rescue-from-a-oauthunauthorized-exception-in-a-ruby-on-rails-applicatio) and [How do I access the Rack environment from within Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848591/how-do-i-access-the-rack-environment-from-within-rails)

Answer (score 4):

We've purposefully left `Apartment` pretty minimal to allow you the handle the exception itself without really needing any Rails specific setup.

I'd do something *similar* to what @jenn is doing above, but I wouldn't bother setting a rack env and dealing with it later, just handle the response completely in rack.

It's typical for instance that you maybe just want to redirect back to `/` on `SchemaNotFound`

You could do something like

```
module MyApp
  class Apartment < ::Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
    def call(env)
      super
    rescue ::Apartment::TenantNotFound
      [302, {'Location' => '/'}, []]
    end
  end
end
```

This is a pretty raw handling of the exception. If you need something to happen more on the Rails side, then @jenn's answer should also work.

Check out the [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack) for more details

Comment: FYI trying to redirect to '/' will cause an infinite redirect, we need to parse out the root_url, doing this in rack is a bit nasty so bubbling up to ActionController is probably a good idea.